# how to link another html page to a poster image in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var columnBlock = $('<div class="col-md-2">');
var imagePoster = $('<img>');
var selectButton = $('<a href="secondPage.html"><button class="selectButton"></button></a>');

var movieID = results[i].id;

imagePoster.attr('movie-id', movieID);
imagePoster.attr('src', 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + results[i].poster_path);

selectButton.text("Select Movie");
selectButton.attr('movie-id', movieID);

columnBlock.append(imagePoster);
columnBlock.append(selectButton);
$('.row').append(columnBlock);
```

I want to make the imagePoster link to the secondPage.html and i tired the same method as i did with the button but it takes away all the poster images on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this one: `columnBlock.append(imagePoster);`

**Add** this : `var imagePoster_link = $('<a href="AnOtHeR.UrL">');`
And this: `imagePoster_link.append(imagePoster);`
And this : `columnBlock.append(imagePoster_link);`

Just before : `columnBlock.append(selectButton);` **(unchanged)**

*In short* it puts your `img` inside an ancor element before happending it to the document.